# how to keep the current page after sorting with jquery/datatables?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using http://www.datatables.net version 1.9.4. 
After sorting I want to keep the current page but default behavior redirects me to the first page. Does anybody know a quick solution?

Thanks

Comment: Did my solution work for you..?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, because i can't change jquery.dataTables.js file itself

Comment: So, I need to override the existing behavior outside

Comment: The solution below is to override exisiting behaviour. And why can't you change in the dataTables.js file? I made changes to it before among with changes in their provided stylesheet...

Comment: Because of the requirements on the project. When new version of dataTables.js is released my changes will be erased.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option of state save. See [this link](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"bStateSave": true` instead of the `stateSave: true` mentioned by Pexsol.

Answer (score 0):

The `stateSave` option won't address this as that only deals with page refreshes, not sorting changes. Something like this will do the trick.

```
var page = 0;

var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.on('order', function() {
    if (table.page() !== page) {
        table.page(page).draw('page');
    }
});

table.on('page', function() {
    page = table.page();
});
```

See fiddle [here](http://live.datatables.net/siqaxoqi/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but I just had the same issue recently and maybe my solution might be of help to someone.

DataTable doesn't provide this functionality as after sorting all your data gets sorted so you will be redirected to 1st page as the visible data will be of no importance. But I had to perform a sort only on visible data because of client's requirement.

First you need to disable the table's header click event

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.columns().every( function () {
        var cell = $(this.header());
        cell.off( 'click');    
    });
```

Then add a click event to each column you want to sort and call the custom `sortTable(n)` that takes column index as parameter.

```
<th onclick="sortTable(0)">First Name</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(1)">Last Name</th>


function sortTable(n) {
    if (dir == "asc") {
        table.order([[ n , 'asc' ]].draw(false);
        dir = "desc";
    }
    else if (dir == "desc") {
        table.order([[ n , 'desc' ]].draw(false);
        dir = "asc";
    }
}
```

You'll also need to initialize the `dir` variable globally and set it to a default direction `asc/desc`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this J-Query to stay on page.

```
   [Code]

 function refreshPage() {
 var page_y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop;
 window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + 
  page_y;
 }
 window.onload = function () {
 setTimeout(refreshPage, 350000);
 if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1) {
    var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&") 
    [0].split("=");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = match[1];
  }
 }

       [/Code]
```